# VimService() initialization is too slow

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, timeout, vsphere

I use the following method to connect vSphere API with .NET C#.
I am able to connect but the constructor for new VimService() takes too much time to be initialized.

I have two questions regarding this?

1. What can be the possible reason for this latency(servers are in the
   same network)?
2. How can I make this initialization faster?

---

```
public void Connect(string url, string username, string password) {
     if (_service != null) {
        Disconnect();
     }
     _service = new VimService(); // it takes almost 1 minute to respond
     _service.Url = url;
     _service.Timeout = 600000; 
     _service.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

     _sic = _service.RetrieveServiceContent(_svcRef);

     if (_sic.sessionManager != null) {
        _service.Login(_sic.sessionManager, username, password, null);
     }

     _state = ConnectionState.Connected;
     if (AfterConnect != null) {
        AfterConnect(this, new ConnectionEventArgs());
     }
  }
```